# Как объяснить написание НН в словах СОБСТВЕННЫЙ и ВСЕЛЕННАЯ?

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

Как объяснить написание НН в словах *собственный* и *Вселенная*?

Comment: @Лорана, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В слове ''собственный'' суффикс - -ственн-(ый). Выделяется в именах прилагательных, которые обозначают признак или свойство, характеризующиеся тем или отношением к тому, что названо мотивирующим словом (де́вственный, да́рственный, же́нственный, отве́тственный, ***со́бственный,*** у́мственный, я́вственный).

См.: ***Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой***

Answer (score 2):

Объяснить традицией написания:

**собственный** - исторически суфф. -енн-; в отымённых прилагательных суфф. -онн-/-енн- пишется две Н;

**Вселенная** - заимствование из старославянского языка, а в нем оно было калькой
древнегреческого "ойкуменэ" - "обитаемый мир" (повесть И. Ефремова "На краю Ойкумены"). Старославянское происхождение слова видно сразу: русская форма звучала бы - "вселённая". В старославянском это было  **причастие  от  глаг. сов. вида вселить,** превратившееся в существительное.

Иногда правописание можно объяснить **традицией**, здесь как раз такой случай. 
Исторически здесь два суффикса: -ен-н-; две Н, потому что от глагола сов. вида.

Но вот интересно, что Викисловарь приводит современное членение  *в-сел-ен-н-ая*
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%    Вот это странно.

И вообще в словарях разноброд: и *вселе/н/ая*, и *вселенн/ая*

Comment: Людмила, а по какому справочнику вы выделяете суффикс енн?

Comment:  А я не по справочнику,по собственному разумению. Собственный-от "собьство"("персона","совокупность личных свойств", "свойство", в др.-русск. было ещё и сущ. "собина"-собственность).Значит, образовалось ещё тогда с помощью суфф.-енн-. А сейчас нам нужно не членение на морфемы, а объяснение орфографии. Оно-в др.-р. словообразовании. ВСЕЛЕННАЯ- в ст.-слав. было причастие, но тогда таких правил не было - писали с одной- н-, а теперь есть, и если это по виду страдательное причастие прош.вр., образованное от глагола на -ИТЬ (вселить), то суфф.-ЕНН-, а на -АТЬ- -А- + -н-,-нн-.

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Слово "Вселенная" — страдательное причастие от глагола "вселять", образованное с помощью вставки (суффикса) "енн" и означающее "обитаемая", "населённая". 
У Даля находим:

> > ВСЕЛЕННАЯ — вся заселенная, предназначенная для заселения людьми земля

Этимологические словари говорят, что это калька греческого слова "ойкумена", то есть "обитаемая часть мира".

Слово "собственный" — отымённое прилагательное от древнего существительного "собьство", означающего, по сути, "особа" или "свойство".

Итог. И в том, и в другом слове вставка (суффикс) "е**НН**".

Answer (score 0):

"Суффикс" -ственн- - результат сложения трёх суффиксов. Один (-ств-) входит, например, в свой**ств**о, второй (-ен-) - в осво**ен**, третий (-н-) - в плат**н**ый.